# Firefox 71 (macOS) not playing BBC.com videos

Tags: firefox, video

When clicking to view a video on the BBC.com News site using [Firefox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox) 71 browser on [macOS Mojave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave), such as [this page](https://www.bbc.com/news/av/world-australia-50799037/australia-bushfires-footage-shows-fire-crowning-across-treetops), I get a spinning red circle. The video never appears.

[image: screenshot of red spinning circle]

The same video works on Safari on my Mac, and with Safari iOS on an iPad. Only Firefox seems to have the problem.

I have left the default settings in effect on Firefox. Perhaps there is a security setting blocking these videos.

This Question, [*Youtube videos play, not BBC, in Firefox. Chrome OK*](https://superuser.com/questions/253964/youtube-videos-play-not-bbc-in-firefox-chrome-ok) looks similar but is not. That Question, dating back to 2011, refers to the use of [Flash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash). As far as I know, the BBC videos are no longer based on Flash now in 2019.

Comment: Same thing here, running Firefox in Ubuntu. Tried with Vivaldi and it worked. Definitely something Firefox specific.

Comment: That works fine for me in Firefox 71.0 but I *am* able to reproduce the issue is if I try to load the video in a Private Browsing window: then I see the same thing as your screenshot.

Comment: It works here in Firefox inside Kali but not on my iPhone Safari.  Site seems to have been put together strangely